# Does the symbol in an rspec example definition have special meaning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am watching a video series on Rspec. And inside his example group, he has several examples, each of which has a symbol:

[image]

Now that is just a ruby string literal. In normal flow, that `:make` should just be a string not a symbol. Does this have special purpose in Rspec? Why does he do this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have any special meaning in RSpec. Usually, rubyists use `ClassName#method_name` notation (or just `#method_name` when class name could be omitted). Maybe author of that video is just used to refer any names in Ruby as symbols.

More than that, anything written in a string between `it` and `do` is just a human readable name for the test and has nothing to do with RSpec internals.